# Class isn't found in the REPL

Tags: clojure

I have a simple file `tag.clj`:

```
(ns myproject.tag)
; ......
```

I can't load it into the REPL

```
user=> (:use [myproject.tag :as tag])
```

and the error is:

```
CompilerException java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myproject.tag
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: `:use` is just a keyword, you want to either do `(use ...` (i.e. the function) or the keyword version inside a call to `ns`, i.e. `(ns foo.bar (:use ...`. Finally, try to call `(require` or `(ns foo.bar (:require ...` instead of `use`. Incredibly difficult sentence trying to avoid the verb use!

Answer (score 2):

If you're not use-ing or require-ing your package inside a (ns ...) form you should use the `use` or `require` forms, *not* the `:use` keyword.

Also:

Your package should be in a directory named "myproject" which should be in a directory that's in your load-path. If you're using a standard leiningen setup, a valid file path is going to be `src/myproject/tag.clj`.

See https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/require, http://clojure.org/libs and https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/TUTORIAL.md

Comment: @AlanCoromano I updated my answer, note that you cannot use :use (the keyword) outside of a (ns ..) form